# How can I Convert Calendar.toString() into date using SimpleDateFormat.parse()?

Tags: java, android, calendar, simpledateformat

I'm developing an Android app that uses a database, every time that the user insert a new register the current data and time is save in the db using

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

So, When I retrieve the data from the db, got a String like this:

> java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1496007575129,areFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=America/Mexico_City,firstDayOfWeek=1,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=1,ERA=1,YEAR=2017,MONTH=4,WEEK_OF_YEAR=22,WEEK_OF_MONTH=5,DAY_OF_MONTH=28,DAY_OF_YEAR=148,DAY_OF_WEEK=1,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=4,AM_PM=1,HOUR=4,HOUR_OF_DAY=16,MINUTE=39,SECOND=35,MILLISECOND=129,ZONE_OFFSET=-21600000,DST_OFFSET=3600000]

The problem comes when I try convert that String using SimpleDateFormat.parse to display it in a RecyclerView, I get always the same date: 09/04/2017.

This is the code in my RecViewAdapter.java:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder,int position){
    items.moveToPosition(position);

    String s,d,p,f;


    s = items.getString(ConsultaTomas.SISTOLICA);
    holder.systolica.setText(s);

    d = items.getString(ConsultaTomas.DIASTOLICA);
    holder.diastolica.setText(d);

    p = items.getString(ConsultaTomas.PULSO);
    holder.pulso.setText(p);

    f = items.getString(ConsultaTomas.FECHA);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    try {
        holder.fecha.setText(sdf.format(sdf.parse(f)));

    }catch (ParseException e){
        Log.d("PARSINGFECHA","Error al parcear fecha");
    }


}
```

The other data is showed correctly in the RecView and the Calendar String are all diferent, so there is not the same date/hour in these strings. So, the question is:

How can I Convert `Calendar.toString()` into date using `SimpleDateFormat.parse()`?

This is the result running the app in a real device:
[image: two muppets]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to modify the way you store the `Calendar`, call `getTime()` and format it as desired to begin with. For example,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(sdf.format(cal.getTime()));
```

Comment: Thank for your solution, I actually saved the cal.getTime() values in the bd and I convert the values to a date when the query is made in the adapter.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
( GregorianCalendar ) myCal                    // Cast the more general `Calendar` to subclass `GregorianCalendar`. 
.toZonedDateTime()                             // Convert from terrible legacy class `GregorianCalendar` to its modern replacement `ZonedDateTime`. 
.toLocalDate()                                 // Extract just the date, without the time-of-day and without the time zone. Returns a `LocalDate` object.
.format(                                       // Generate text representing the value of this `LocalDate` object.
    DateTimeFormatter
    .ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT )      // Automatically localize the text.
    .withLocale( new Locale( "es" , "ES" ) )   // Specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms to use in localization.
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy classes `Calendar` & `GregorianCalendar`.

When you encounter a `Calendar` object, immediately convert to its replacement, `ZonedDateTime`, assuming your object is actually a `GregorianCalendar`.

```
if( myCal instanceOf GregorianCalendar )
{
    GregorianCalendar gc = ( GregorianCalendar ) myCal ;  // Cast from more general class to the specific class.
    ZonedDateTime zdt = gc.toZonedDateTime() ;
}
```

You apparently are interested only in the date portion, without the time-of-day and without the time zone. So extract a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = zdt.toLocalDate() ;  // Ignore time-of-day and time zone.
```

Generate text in your desired format.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/uuuu" ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

Or better: Let *java.time* automatically localize for you.

```
Locale locale = new Locale( "es" , "ES" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).